# command : Delete[] x

Tags: pointers, allocation

I have the following simple code. I allocate dynamically memory for 3 doubles, I assign to each double a number and after I deallocate the memory but as one can see if runs the code the only difference before and after the deletion (delete[] x) and the only difference is for the first double of the vector. I can't understand why the content of the first element of the vector changed and the content of x remained the same with the same address of memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    double * x;
    x = new double [3];
    x[0] = 1; x[1]=3; x[2]=5;
    std::cout << x[0] << " " << x[1] << " " << x[2] << "\n";
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    delete[] x;
    std::cout << x[0] << " " << x[1] << " " << x[2] << "\n";
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, this is undefined behaviour; `x` is read after it is deleted.

Comment: What do you mean by "this is undefined behavior" ??? Did you execute it ? I see the below after my running
1 3 5
0x1acc010
0 3 5
0x1acc010
The x points to the same address and only the first element of the vector changed.

Comment: The term “undefined behavior” is the technical term used by the C++ standard to mean “all bets are off about what happens if you try this.” If you access memory after deleting it, you get undefined behavior, meaning that in principle literally anything could in principle happen. It could instantly crash your program. It could show you randomly-generated values. Or (in principle, but not in practice) it could create a sentient AI that enslaves humanity. :-)

Comment: Ok. But another question is the memory that allocated with x free after the deletion?